# Variable assignment in a conditional?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

What would this evaluate to? I know it looks funny but I was looking at a practice exam and saw this:

```
if (number = 1) { echo "C1 is true"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are **assigning variables** it always returns `true` when the assigned variable is not causing `false`.So it will go to the if and echo the output.And consider that **it mainly depends on the value that you are assigning**.

Suppose if you do like

```
if (number = 0) {  // if(number = false)
    echo "C1 is true"; 
} else {
    echo "C1 is false";
}
```

It will prints `C1 is false`.Bec it will indirectly indicate like

```
if(0) // if(false)
```

which is a `false`.

Comment: Isn't this only case for variables that evaluate to true? I believe if(something = false) { ... } would evaluate to false.

Comment: It doesn't return `true`, it returns *the assigned value*.

Comment: @deceze I told that thing in BOLD.see once

Comment: It's still wrong. `=` does not "always return `true` unless it returns `false`". It returns *the assigned value*.

Comment: See it..`it always returns true when the variable is not causing`.I didnt explain in my words with that I think so...that's Y I have added again it

Comment: What's so hard about stating correctly what it actually does? *`=` returns its right hand operand.* `console.log(foo = 'bar')` → `'bar'`

Comment: I also stated same thing if u see...Ok let it stop our discussion here.It will be understand if some saw my example.Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator `=` returns the assigned value. What does that mean? For example, the `+` operator in `1 + 2` returns the sum of two numbers; the *value* of the *expression* `1 + 2` is `3`. In the same vein, the *value* of the *expression* `number = 1` is `1`. That's why this works:

```
a = b = c = 1;
```

So you're assigning `1` to `number`, the resulting value of which is `1`, which is evaluated by `if`, which equals `true`.

Comment: So it's basically saying "if (1) { //stuff }" ?